# Puppeteer confirm

Tags: javascript, confirm, puppeteer

I am trying to learn puppeteer. I have successfully scripted a login to a page and some navigation. Then I have it click on a button. The page throws up a window.confirm and I want my script to accept this to continue to the next step but I can’t figure out how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is an option in puppeteer to emulate key-presses, I've a feeling closing a confirm dialog box is as simple as presses enter,.. So maybe -> `page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just done a simple test here, when a dialog box comes up on confirm.  Simply pressing enter will close the dialog.

So what we can do in puppeteer, is do exactly that.
I knocked up a quick webpage that had a confirm box,..

eg.

```
<div>Before confirm</div>
<script>
  window.confirm("confirm");
  document.write("<div>After Confirm</div>");
</script>
```

Now our puppeteer script.

```
await delay(1000);
await page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));  
await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
await browser.close();
```

Doing the above my screenshot is

```
Before confirm
After Confirm
```

Exactly what we expect if pressing the confirm dialog,..
ps.  `delay` is just a simple promises based setTimeout to wait, so we have chance for the confirm dialog to appear.

If you currently don't have a promise delay function, here is one for you to use.

```
const delay = (ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

UPDATE: Unfortunately dialogs don't respond the keypress reliably.  But puppeter does have a dialog event we can attach too.

```
page.on("dialog", (dialog) => {
  console.log("dialog");
  dialog.accept();
});
```

You can even dismiss, and read what message etc was sent.  more info here->
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-dialog

Comment: Thanks, Keith. So I tried that and nothing happens. 

Strangely, if I manually enter a return the action completes.

Comment: Just to confirm, I used the example you posted above without any change and the same thing as I wrote above. I get nothing. 

Google Chrome 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Is there anything I need to do to set my environment?

Comment: `without any change` Did you implement the promise delay function as I did not show that.  Also did you not get any errors?  If the button press didn't work you should have at least got `Before confirm` showing.

Comment: Actually I wasn't familiar with promises so I did this: 
  await page.waitFor(1000);

which I confirmed does introduce a pause. The problem is not in the lack of a delay. The Return is simply not doing what is expected or not firing. I don't understand why however.

Comment: For clarity, here's what I ran: 

`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 100})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
 
 
 await page.goto('file:///Users/bierman/Documents/Applications/bin/arris/test.html')
 await page.focus()
    await page.waitFor(1000);
 await page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));  
 await browser.close()
})()`

Comment: I don't think `page.waitFor` is the same, if the page is already ready it's not going to wait at all.  I'll update my snippet with a simple Promise based `delay` function, try this.  Ps.  I did try the above, and for me worked as expected, so hopefully it's just the delay your missing, as it's not getting chance for the alert to appear.

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I must still be doing something wrong. I tried your example and it isn't working for me. Since comments are limited here, I set this up here. Maybe you can tell me what I've done wrong. https://codepen.io/mbierman/pen/KoLpKe?editors=1111

Comment: Ah!, right I see your problem.  `await page.goto(`  In the example we have done, the alert is showing instantly, and were telling puppeter to wait for page load.  Obviously in this case because you have alert at start up the page will never load until the alert is clicked.. ,  A simple solution here, is just take out the `await` on the `page goto`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That did make your example work. My actual issue is more like this https://codepen.io/mbierman/pen/Brewjd which has a button that is pressed that brings up a confirm. I can get up to the same point where the confirm comes up and the return event is never firing off. In this case, the page has already loaded before the button is pressed so I don't understand what is preventing this from working.

Comment: Yes, strange!!!..  I've found the proper way to handle this anyway.  I'll update my snippet above,..

Comment: I will give it a try that looks promising. A side note: I notice that if you tab in chrome it switches which button is selected but if after tabbing you hit return you always get a true event. If you want to cancel you have to hit escape. Not very nice. But I will give your suggestion a try.  Thank you so much! 

Comment: @Keith the `dialog.accept()` works fine in `head` mode but does not work in `headless` mode. Puppeteer just ignores the confirm alert. Even looked at this issue but got nothing - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718235

I'm using Puppeteer: 1.11.0 and Chrome: 72.0.3626.96 on Linux.

Comment: I took some time to learn that the page.on("dialog" ...) code must be *before* any code that triggers the dialog. I actually had to read at puppeteer docs directly to learn this. If possible, it might help other users if this becomes well shown together with the page.on("dialog" ...) code. Or it was just me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The `dialog.accept()` approach works fine for me in `headless` mode on linux, using the latest puppeteer.

Answer (score 5):

The confirmation prompt is triggered by the global function `confirm(<string>)` which is at `window.confirm`. That function freezes the execution of the script until a response is given, then returns it to the caller. If the user accepts the prompt the returned value will be `true`.

Since we're working on a custom browser session in a webpage you can overwrite globals with anything you want.

So before running the action that triggers the confirmation window run

```
await page.evaluate(`window.confirm = () => true`)
```

Then when the page code calls `confirm()` it will get a `true` response immediately without showing any prompt.

Comment: Thank you! I no longer have that modem so I am not maintaining the script in question right now, but this is good to know.

Comment: Saved my life! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, Keith! It is now working like a charm. If anyone is interested I have posted it here.

https://gist.github.com/mbierman/5b3e671fa4e848eec899ff486d0cdc26

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * @name Reboot Arris modem. 
 *
 * @desc Puppeteer script for rebooting an Arris modem. 
 * since the specific navigation for your modem will vary, this 
 * is more of an example and isn't guaranteed to work for your particular
 * modem. 
 * Many thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith for his help!
 *
 */

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const screenshot = 'arris.png';

/* Enter your user name and password here between the 's */
const USER = '';
const PASS = '';

    const delay = (ms) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true})
    const page = await browser.newPage()

        console.log("Login...");
    await page.goto('http://192.168.0.1/login.asp');
    await page.type('#id_username', USER, { delay: 10 });
    await page.type('input[type="password"]', PASS, { delay: 10 });
    await page.click('[value="Login"]');
        console.log("Going home...");
    await page.goto('http://192.168.0.1/home.asp');
    await page.click('#alertExitButton');
        console.log("Config...");
    await page.goto('http://192.168.0.1/RgConfiguration.asp');
    console.log('Submit request...');
    page.click('input[type="submit"]');
    console.log('Pause...');

    await page.on("dialog", (dialog) => {
    console.log("Dialog is up...");
        delay(1000);
    console.log("Accepted...");
    dialog.accept();
        delay(1000);
    });

        await delay(3000);
        console.log("Exiting.");
    browser.close();
    process.exit(1);
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

We are building objects to pass so it's a little different but I thought I would share.

We create an object for the operation:

```
type: "operation",
name: "Touch Delete button from tracks-hero-tmp",
description: "Click and confirm delete and verify track cluster is 1 less",
actions: [
  { method: 'waitForSelector', value: '[tg-name=track_hero_delete_btn]' },
  { method: 'focus', value: '[tg-name=track_hero_delete_btn]' },
  { method: 'click', value: '[tg-name=track_hero_delete_btn]', accept_dialog: 'false' },
  { method: 'screenshot' }
],
```

Then the "accept_dialog" is set to a boolean that gets passed into an async function and we set the dialog response like this:

```
  if (accept_dialog) {
    await dialog.accept();
  } else {
    await dialog.dismiss();
  }
```

Hope this helps someone. :)