# Puppeteer: Close geolocation permission request

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How do I use Puppeteer to close Chrome's geolocation permission request? I've placed `page.on` everywhere, and tried using `confirm`, `dialog`, `alert` and `prompt`. I've also read the following links, but couldn't find a solution:

- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1213
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1475
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v0.12.0/docs/api.md#class-dialog
- https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v0.12.0/docs/api.md#event-dialog
- [Puppeteer confirm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728669/puppeteer-confirm)
- [Puppeteer opening chrome instance for each file at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50557418/puppeteer-opening-chrome-instance-for-each-file-at-once/50557444#50557444)
- https://gist.github.com/mbierman/5b3e671fa4e848eec899ff486d0cdc26

My script:

```js
console.log("\nProcess Started");
//sample webpage
let webPage = "https://www.mta.org.nz/find-an-mta/?location=us";

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1600,
    height: 900
  });

  try {
    await page.goto(webPage);
    await page.waitForSelector("body");
    await console.log("Loaded: " + webPage);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + webPage + "\n" + err);
  }

  await page.waitFor(10000);

  browser.close();
  await console.log("Process Ended \n");
};
main();
```

Comment: I don't see a dialog on that page. I see a geolocation permissions request from Chrome though. If that was what you're referring to, it's [not yet supported](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/846). But you might want to try [patching `navigator.getlocation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/846#issuecomment-360105636) as a workaround.

Comment: Yes that is what I am referring to. I did not realize it was something different. Will try your suggestion once I've learnt how to implement them. I figured I was doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Puppeteer API (v1.5.0) currently [does not support catching permission requests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/846) (which would've allowed granting/denying the geolocation permission), but as a workaround, you could [patch `navigator.geolocation`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/846#issuecomment-360105636) in [`page.evaluateOnNewDocument()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/eb53a8f/docs/api.md#pageevaluateonnewdocumentpagefunction-args):

```js
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function (cb) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cb({
        'coords': {
          accuracy: 21,
          altitude: null,
          altitudeAccuracy: null,
          heading: null,
          latitude: 23.129163,
          longitude: 113.264435,
          speed: null
        }
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
});

await page.goto('https://www.mta.org.nz/find-an-mta/?location=us')
```

[demo](https://puppeteersandbox.com/IZA8FJae)

Comment: This is nice, I think your solution may be better than mine. I could not get mine to work in headless mode.

Answer (score 6):

```
// page.setGeolocation(options)

const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();
await context.overridePermissions(url, ['geolocation']);
```

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.18.1&show=api-browsercontextoverridepermissionsorigin-permissions

Comment: You can see the list of all permissions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked with "headless: false" but could not get it to work "headless: true".

1. Added " --user-data-dir=C:/Users/[USER]/PATH/TO/MY/DIRECTORY/myUserDataDir " to the command line(Read Note 1)
2. Added " userDataDir: './myUserDataDir' " to my script in puppeteer.launch().
3. Set as " headless: false " in puppeteer.launch().
4. Run script from command line. 
   " node C:/Users/[USER]/PATH/TO/MY/DIRECTORY/script.js  --user-data-dir=C:/Users/[USER]/PATH/TO/MY/DIRECTORY/myUserDataDir "(Read Note 1)
5. Chromium open's, page loads and when popup opens. Click popup button and then close the browser. Selection is now saved
6. The next time the script is run the popup will not open and the page will finish loading.(Read Note 2)

Note 1 : --user-data-dir=  in command line is recommended but does not seem to have any effect. This script works without it.

Note 2 : I cannot get this to work in headless mode. It hangs! I suspect something needs to be manually changed in myUserDataDir files. Does anyone know?

```
console.log("\nProcess Started");

//sample webpage
let webPage = "https://www.mta.org.nz/find-an-mta/?";

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        userDataDir: "C:/Users/[USER]/PATH/TO/MY/DIRECTORY/myUserDataDir", //New line added
        headless: false
        });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1600, height: 900});

    try{
        await page.goto(webPage); 
        await page.waitForSelector("body"); 
        await console.log("Loaded: " + webPage);
    }
    catch(err){             
        console.log("Error: " + webPage + "\n" + err);          
    }

    await page.waitFor(10000);

    browser.close();
    await console.log("Process Ended \n");  
};
main();
```